# Disable scroll for other elements until target div is of a certain height?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have my nav menu as full screen and it is connected to the scroll behaviour where as I scroll down the height of the navbar image shrinks.

However when I scroll, the page scrolls past the content below it. I want to disable scrolling for elements below the navbar until the navbar image's height is of a certain amount.

How would I do this?
Here's the sample code for what I currently have working:

```
var scrollCn = function(quantity)
{
  var scrollTop = Math.round((window.pageYOffset || document.scrollTop)  - (document.clientTop || 100));
  
  var size = 100 - Math.round(((scrollTop / quantity) || 0));
  console.log($(document).scrollTop());
  if(size <= 10) size = 10;

  
  document.querySelector('#header-img').setAttribute('style', 'height: '+size+'vh; width: ' +size+ '%;');
}
```